# CAGradientLayer is not getting the shape

Tags: ios, swift, gradient, shapes, layer

I am creating a CAGradientLayer with the shape of a horseshoe. It seems it's not taking the path and it just draws a square with shadow. What am I missing ?

```
let gradientLayerContainer = CAShapeLayer()
        let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
        let segmentGradientPath = UIBezierPath.horseshoe(
            center: centerPoint,
            innerRadius: (bounds.width / 2) - config.ringWidth,
            outerRadius: bounds.width / 2,
            startAngle: segmentTapped.startAngle,
            endAngle: segmentTapped.endAngle)
        gradientLayerContainer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        gradientLayerContainer.path = segmentGradientPath.cgPath

        let end = centerPoint
        let start = centerPoint.shifted(outerRadius, with: segmentTapped.centerAngle)
        gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: start.x / bounds.width, y: start.y / bounds.height)
        gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: end.x / bounds.width, y: end.y / bounds.height)
        gradient.colors = [UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.0).cgColor, UIColor.white.cgColor]
        gradient.frame = segmentGradientPath.bounds
        gradient.mask = gradientLayerContainer
        gradient.locations = [0, 1]


        horseshoeLayer.addSublayer(gradientLayerContainer)
        gradientLayerContainer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mask belongs to the gradient layer.  The gradient layer does not belong to the mask.  Also the mask color needs to be opaque everywhere you want the gradient to show (you are using clear which is the opposite).

Here is a Playground example of the correct hierarchy:

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import UIKit

let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300)
let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
let maskPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: rect)
maskLayer.fillColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
maskLayer.path = maskPath.cgPath
gradient.colors = [UIColor.blue.cgColor, UIColor.red.cgColor]
gradient.mask = maskLayer
gradient.locations = [0, 1]

let view = UIView(frame: rect)
view.layer.addSublayer(gradient)
gradient.frame = view.bounds
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view
```